# How to install PGlogical from sources on Freebsd?

Tags: postgresql, freebsd

I have Postgresql 9.5 server on Freebsd. I try to install PGlogical (http://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/) from sources. But when I downloaded tarball and unpacked it, I saw only these files:

```
pglogical-1.0.1 ls -la
total 480
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel   1536 Mar 24 11:51 .
drwxrwxrwt  16 root  wheel   1024 Mar 24 15:42 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000       8 Jan 19 15:39 .distgitrev
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000      11 Jan 19 15:39 .distgittag
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000     169 Dec 31 12:33 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000     216 Dec 27 15:59 .gitmodules
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    6240 Jan 18 06:42 Makefile
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000   23965 Jan 18 06:42 README.md
drwxrwxr-x   4 1000  1000     512 Jan 18 06:42 compat
drwxrwxr-x   2 1000  1000     512 Jan 19 14:39 expected
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000     893 Jan 19 14:39 pglogical--1.0.0--1.0.1.sql
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    9496 Jan 18 06:42 pglogical--1.0.0.sql
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    9504 Jan 18 06:42 pglogical--1.0.1.sql
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000   12670 Jan 18 06:42 pglogical.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000     184 Dec 22 15:27 pglogical.control.in
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    1796 Jan 18 06:42 pglogical.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000   43489 Jan 18 06:42 pglogical_apply.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000   13960 Jan 18 06:42 pglogical_conflict.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    2038 Dec 19 13:27 pglogical_conflict.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000   38525 Jan 18 06:42 pglogical_create_subscriber.c
drwxrwxr-x   2 1000  1000    1024 Jan 18 07:32 pglogical_dump
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    1367 Dec 19 13:27 pglogical_fe.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000     533 Dec  1 09:35 pglogical_fe.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000   41913 Jan 18 06:42 pglogical_functions.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    8748 Dec 19 13:27 pglogical_hooks.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    4126 Dec 19 13:27 pglogical_manager.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000   23212 Jan 18 06:42 pglogical_node.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    1992 Dec 19 13:27 pglogical_node.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    9323 Dec 19 13:27 pglogical_proto.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    1431 Sep 30 07:51 pglogical_proto.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    5493 Dec 19 13:27 pglogical_queue.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    1026 Dec 19 13:27 pglogical_queue.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    4832 Jan 18 06:42 pglogical_relcache.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    1147 Dec 19 13:27 pglogical_relcache.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000   24719 Dec 19 13:27 pglogical_repset.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    2770 Jan 18 06:42 pglogical_repset.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    4126 Dec 19 13:27 pglogical_rpc.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000     711 Dec  1 09:35 pglogical_rpc.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000   34577 Jan 18 06:42 pglogical_sync.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    2472 Dec 19 13:27 pglogical_sync.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    9808 Jan 18 06:42 pglogical_worker.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    2898 Dec 19 13:27 pglogical_worker.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000    4667 Oct 28 08:21 regress-pg_hba.conf
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000  1000     602 Jan 18 06:42 regress-postgresql.conf
drwxrwxr-x   2 1000  1000     512 Jan 19 14:39 sql
```

And I didn't see configure file and other. How to install this tarball? OS - Freebsd 10.2

Answer (score 0):

You can install pglogical from sources only using PostgreSQL sources:

1. Download sources of PostgreSQL of necessary version.
2. You also need pglogical_output extension and its sources. You can read about it in the [documentation](http://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/pglogical-docs/). Download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/postgres/tree/dev/pglogical/contrib/pglogical_output).
3. Configure PostgreSQL. More about it in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/install-procedure.html).
4. Copy downloaded sources of pglogical and pglogical_output to directories **contrib/pglogical** and **contrib/pglogical_output**.
5. Execute commands:

   cd <path-to-postgres-sources>/contrib/pglogical
   make install
   cd <path-to-postgres-sources>/contrib/pglogical_output
   make install
6. Read the [documentation](http://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/pglogical-docs/) to setup pglogical.

Answer (score -1):

Did you read the README file? It will probably tell you to use make, as there is a Makefile